# loading different css base on .env file on nuxt.config.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt.config.js

I am trying to load a different css base on my .env file because I have two - three types of application that has different designs.

my nuxt.config.js looks something like this

```js
export default {
  mode: "spa",
  css: process.env.APP_TYPE == 1 ? ["~/assets/scss/app1.scss"] : ["~/assets/scss/app2.scss"]
}
```

I would like to load 2-3 different scss base on my .env file

Comment: Was the attempt successful? What is the question?

Comment: the css attritube only accepts array so it didn't work as I wanted to...

Comment: Your code as following should work fine IMO. Are you sure this is working great without the conditional?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function before export statement in config that would return css-array. For example:

```js
const getCss = () => {
  return process.env.APP_TYPE == 1 
   ? ["~/assets/scss/app1.scss"] 
   : ["~/assets/scss/app2.scss"]
}
export default {
  mode: "spa",
  css: getCss()
}
```